# R, remove list where there is no matching regular expression

Tags: regex, r

After I parsed the website, I got this list and I'd like to only keep the list where there is no "#M" in the list.

```
 > a
[1] "/t5/SIM-CFD/td-p/3423843"                            
[2] "/t5/SIM-CFD/td-p/3423843/page/2"                     
[3] "/t5/SIM-CFD/m-p/4305885#M2261"                       
[4] "/t5/Support/m-p/4467611#M2801"
```

so my result will be like the below.

```
 > result
[1] "/t5/SIM-CFD/td-p/3423843"                            
[2] "/t5/SIM-CFD/td-p/3423843/page/2"
```

I tried the below but it doesn't work..

```
a[grepl("#M", a , ]
```

Any advice? It sounds so simple, but I cannot think of the solution.
Thank you!

Comment: typo? `a[!grepl("#M", a)]` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a[!sapply(a,function(x) grepl("#M",x))]
```

Comment: @user1486507 Even Karsten's works. It's a simpler way to do it- and better imo, but mine is a bit more generic I guess.